# Stripe VeriFone P400 device

Tags: javascript, sdk, stripe-payments

I have a Stripe VeriFone P400 device and I need to implement NFC touchless payment integrating with our Web application.

I am not able to find any docs on the Stripe related to NFC touchless payment.
Please anyone can confirm if there is any Stripe JavaScript API/SDK for the web application or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call [`collectPaymentMethod`](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/js-api-reference#collect-payment-method) to put the reader in the state to get [payment details](https://stripe.com/docs/terminal/payments#collect) you should be able to present any contactless card.